# filters not working on specific workspace rally

Tags: rally

I have two workspaces 
When I load my application on one workspace it works with the filters but when I use same code it doesn't work.
Then I tried commenting out filters then it gave me whole records. Not able to figure what's the difference,
I am using Rally `sdk2.0rc3`
below are my code snippet

`this._startDate` value is `2014-09-10`

`this._endDate` value is `2015-03-03`

and when I print operation it gives false

and `iterations = []`

@nickm help me

```
            _onDataLoaded: function() {
                console.log("this.getContext().getProject()._ref", this.getContext().getProject()._ref);
                console.log("this._startDate", this._startDate);
                console.log("this._endDate", this._endDate);
                var project_oid = this.getContext().getProject()._ref;

                var startDateFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter', {
                    property: 'StartDate',
                    operator: '>',
                    value: this._startDate
                });
                startDateFilter = startDateFilter.and({
                    property: 'StartDate',
                    operator: '<',
                    value: this._endDate
                });
                startDateFilter = startDateFilter.and({
                    property: 'StartDate',
                    operator: '!=',
                    value: null
                });
                var endDateFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter', {
                    property: 'EndDate',
                    operator: '<',
                    value: this._endDate
                });
                endDateFilter = endDateFilter.and({
                    property: 'EndDate',
                    operator: '>',
                    value: this._startDate
                });
                endDateFilter = endDateFilter.and({
                    property: 'EndDate',
                    operator: '!=',
                    value: null
                });
                var filter = startDateFilter.or(endDateFilter);
                //filter.toString();
                Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                    model: 'Iteration',
                    limit: Infinity,
                    context: {
                        project: project_oid,
                        projectScopeDown: true,
                        projectScopeUp: false
                    },                          
                    fetch: ['Name','Project', 'StartDate', 'EndDate', 'Parent', 'Children'],
                    autoLoad: true,
                    filters: [
                        filter
                    ],
                    listeners: {
                        load: this._loadGrid,
                        scope:this
                    }                   
                }, this);   
            },
            _loadGrid: function(store, iterations, operation) {
                console.log("hi there", operation);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess was that if the same code works in one workspace and does not work in another workspace, and the culprit is the filter based on date values, check if your workspaces have different date format. For example like this:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

But I tested '2015-02-06' value in a workspace that using mm/dd/yyyy format and it worked.

In any case, if it works in one workspace and does not work in another chances are this is not an issue with the code but with the data. Maybe in the second workspace the same query returns 0 results. Also, depending on the meaning of the dates used in code, it is possible to avoid hard-coding dates. For example, to get current iteration try this:

```
var today = new Date().toISOString();
filters: [
                {
                    property: 'StartDate',
                    operator: '<=',
                    value: today
                },
                {
                    property: 'EndDate',
                    operator: '>=',
                    value: today
                }
            ]
```

Comment: Thanks nick, yes I used this `toISOString()` on my dates, and it worked. Thanks a lot